# How can I stop a sound from keep playing when navigating to a different screen in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio

I'm creating an app, where it plays a sound when pressing a pressable place.
When navigating to a different screen, it still keeps playing.
How can I stop playing?

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";
import { Audio } from "expo-av";
import { useSoundContext } from "../context/SoundContextProvider";

export default function SoundPlayer({ voice, children }) {
  const { sound, setSound } = useSoundContext();

  async function playSound() {
    console.log("Loading Sound");
    if (sound) {
      console.log("Unloading Sound");
      await sound.unloadAsync();
    }
    const { sound: newSound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(voice);
    setSound(newSound);

    console.log("Playing Sound");
    await newSound.playAsync();
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={playSound}>{children}</TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Thank you in advance.